# Error in receiving custom headers from microsoft edge browser in rails

Tags: angular, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-5, microsoft-edge

My backend application is in `RoR` and front-end app is in `Angular2` 
I am getting error in receiving headers in microsoft edge browser in production, the code works fine in other browsers like safari, chrome, mozila.
I am not getting the header `'auth_token'` in `Edge` browser but it is working on localhost.

Comment: check this link https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt/issues/173 and see the header name cases in request.

Comment: @Prithvi: This is not the issue in my case. I am not able to receive any custom headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the header name from `auth_token` to `auth-token` and on the server side I received this like `HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN`.

Edge doesn't allow the underscores in the headers while other browsers does.